# Using sapply to sample with pre-defined probability

Tags: r, sample, sapply

I'm using `sample` function with pre-defined probability.

I made this code and it worked fine. However, there is no way to check I've done my job right. Would anybody check my work and evaluate it?

```
df <- structure(list(A=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"),
                     probs=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.3,0.7,0.9)),
                Names = c("name","probs"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1:7))

df$pred<-sapply(df$probs,function(x) sample(c("Yes","No"),1,prob=c(x,1-x),replace=TRUE))
```

In `df`, `probs` is pre-defined probability of saying `"yes"`. I used `sapply` with each `probs`, and applied `sample` function.

Comment: 1) Use `set.seed(<integer>)` to make it reproducible; 2) if you are sampling only one at a time, there's no need for `replace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to check this would be to increase the sample size and check the proportion.

```
n <- 1e6
set.seed(123)
sapply(df$probs,function(x) 
          table(sample(c("Yes","No"),n,prob=c(x,1-x),replace=TRUE))/n)


#       [,1]     [,2]    [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]
#No  0.80006 0.599886 0.40003 0.200072 0.699906 0.299314 0.100044
#Yes 0.19994 0.400114 0.59997 0.799928 0.300094 0.700686 0.899956
```

As we can see that all the `"Yes"` values is almost same as `df$probs` we can say that what we have is correct.

Comment: This is very intuitive and clear explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

another option using "purrr"

```
library(purrr)
sample_fun <- function(probs){
  sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10^6, prob = c(probs, 1 - probs ), replace = T)
}

map(df$probs, ~ sample_fun(.x)) %>% 
  map_dbl( ~ mean(.x == "Yes")) %>% 
  purrr::set_names(df$A)
```